# shell script check if command eval result is a specific value

Tags: linux, shell

I have a small snippet here that is part of a shell-script used to call an API and retreive a response. I wish to check for an empty API response by seeing if the returned string is an empty square-brackets string [] - and if it is, do a break and abort execution.

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
cmd = 'some curl api request being formatted here'
eval $cmd
```

and this is what I'm currently trying

```
cmd = 'some curl api request being formatted here'
if
     eval $cmd == '[]' then echo 'Empty response from API' | break
     else continue
fi
```

Any suggestions for achieving this?

Comment: Why `eval`? It is much easier if directly call `curl ...` within `$()` and check if `= '[]'`

Comment: There is a specific purpose why do need `eval` or ?

Comment: There are some calculations and concatenations being done inside the cmd-string. But I can try calling it directly as you propose.

Comment: I'll post the answer and you guide me on what you want to change

Comment: PS: `break` and `continue`, are you in a loop?

Comment: Yes, it's in a loop

Comment: Ok, I can simplify your code then

Comment: Since you are in a loop there is no need to use `continue` but only `break` to exit the loop

Comment: Even if you're forming the command dynamically you shouldn't use `eval`. Generate an array instead and you avoid the security risks inherent in treating data as code. See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time) demonstrating how to use arrays for this purpose, and [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) describing why _not_ to use eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
# Call curl and save response
_response="$(curl ...)"

# Check response
if [ "$_response" = '[]' ]; then
  # Empty response
  printf 'Empty response from API\n'
  break
fi

# Continue ...
```